# How to target destroy resources in terraform cloud, should I use TF_CLI_ARGS environment variable

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-cloud

I would like to destroy specific resources through terraform cloud. I found that TF_CLI_ARGS_plan will do a target plan. But I cannot find any variable to target destroy. Kindly let me know if this is possible in terraform cloud.

I tried TF_CLI_ARGS_destroy but it seems that variable is not working.

Answer (score -1):

The above commands are used to create environment variables and to customize behavior

> ```
> TF_CLI_ARGS_init
> TF_CLI_ARGS_plan
> TF_CLI_ARGS_apply
> ```

So that the targeted plan and apply can be made.

[image]

Terraform Cloud uses the export command to populate the shell with environment variables.

creating an environment variable named `TF_CLI_ARGS_plan` is to target a particular resource, same way you can make use of  terraform destroy command with target option , which uses terraform apply in destroy mode:

Below Command worked for me:

```
terraform destroy -target <give RESOURCE_TYPE.NAME> -target <RESOURCE_TYPE2.NAME  if required>
```

[image]

**Reference**: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12917

Answer (score -2):

Put the `destroy` into the `TF_CLI_ARGS_plan=-destroy --target....`